# CakePHP Get absolute links of images from uploads folder

Tags: php, ios, image, web-services, cakephp

Hi guys I could use some help on getting absolute URL links to show images with cakePHP without HTML helper.

So I wrote a webservice(webservice communicates in json) for an application that is being ran on iOS. Now the problem is people can upload images from the application to my webservice, they get stored in webroot/uploads folder.

Now I want to show the images on my application in real size if they click on them(using thumbnails for the smaller ones, using a controller which creates thumbnails) the problem is when I point out to webservice.com/uploads/imagename, it says controller uploads can not be found(pretty obivous but hey). So my question is how can I get the absolute links to the images without needing a controller, so when I go to the URL of the image it just shows the image in my browser and on my application, and I can't use views for this cause it needs to show on the iOS application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Sokoo

Comment: Would probably be better if you'd fix the URL rewriting and/or make sure that the filename is correct, as there is no need for a controller when accessing real files that live inside the webroot, such requests normally never even hit CakePHP. **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.7/app/webroot/.htaccess#L3-L4**

Comment: Hmmm okay! Thanks for your answer, I'm going to have a look into the URL rewriting I have absolutely no experience with URL rewriting haha! I'll also have a look into the link you posted but I guess that is the URL rewriting part. As to the filenames, they are all stored in a database too, and we will call the URL to the images from within the iOS application at the hand of an array we get from my webservice with all filenames in it, I just need the direct link to the images from within the webroot and make sure it doesn't screw up the rewriting for my controllers.